# Handling NULL pointers in a generic swap function

Tags: c, pointers, generics

I am writing a generic swap function `genericSwap()` for fun/exercise in `C`. (Let's leave aside the question whether this is a good idea or not.) Since the function internally uses `memcpy()` I need to handle cases where pointers are passed that are `NULL` and in all the other questions regarding generic swap functions this problem seems to be ignored. Here is how I do it so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void genericSwap(void *x, void *y, size_t size);

int main(void)
{
        int num1;
        int num2;

        num1 = 1;
        num2 = 2;

        printf("%d\t%d\n", num1, num2);

        genericSwap(&num1, &num2, sizeof(num1));

        printf("%d\t%d\n", num1, num2);

        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void genericSwap(void *x, void *y, size_t size)
{
        void *temp;

        if (!x || !y) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Trying to pass NULL pointer\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        temp = malloc(size);
        if(!temp) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        memcpy(temp, x, size);
        memcpy(x, y, size);
        memcpy(y, temp, size);

        free(temp);
}
```

This deals with (certainly strange) cases like `genericSwap(NULL, NULL, sizeof(something))` and so on. As you can see (or test if you like), the function currently brutally errors out when a `NULL` pointer is passed. This may not always be the preferred way to handle such cases. Sometimes in a program I may want the function to quietly return control back to the caller which in this case is `main()`. My idea would be to use an empty `return` after each error handling `if`-condition so that `genericSwap()` becomes:

```
void genericSwap(void *x, void *y, size_t size)
{
        void *temp;

        if (!x || !y) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Trying to pass NULL pointer\n");
                return;
        }

        temp = malloc(size);
        if(!temp) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed\n");
                return;
        }

        memcpy(temp, x, size);
        memcpy(x, y, size);
        memcpy(y, temp, size);

        free(temp);
}
```

My question is if the strategies I outlined so far can be considered safe. Additionally, I would like to hear your suggestions on how to improve error handling in these functions.

Comment: Looks more like a question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: You can return a success value from your function instead of `void`, and check it in main. Then handle it on the top level.

Comment: @danielfranca This is a bit border-line. There is a specific goal here of improving the error-handling, I think this question might fit on both SO and CR, about equally well.

Answer (score 1):

There is no magic here. Passing bullshit data is typically undefined behaviour even in custom "library" functions. Printing some stuff is a total non-starter (for instance, `stderr` may be closed).

If you want to sanity check stuff you got, use `assert()` - this stuff can be /ignored/ by the compiler when generating production (i.e. not-development code) and causes the program in question to crash, typically providing nice snapshot of its state, including the backtrace showing how it got there.

Comment: The relation of this answer to the question is barely visible for me.

Comment: The OP has a weird idea of "handling" incorrect arguments for his function. I say it's weird and say what he can do instead if he really wants to check such stuff.

Comment: Of course NULL is handled by a lot of functions, but only if there is any meaningful way to do it (e.g. it denotes an absence of an optional argument). Here NULL is clearly shown as an unacceptable argument and the OP tries to fprintf crap to stderr to note it. That's a completely wrong approach.

Answer (score 1):

> Since the function internally uses memcpy() I need to handle cases where pointers are passed that are NULL

Why?

I mean, it's not *wrong* to do this, but you're talking about argument checking, not actual functionality.  It is not unreasonable to simply document that your function's behavior is defined only if the pointer arguments are each valid pointers to object representations of the specified size.  You cannot test whether the size of the referents is correct, nor whether the pointer arguments are invalid despite being non-`NULL`, so you cannot perform *complete* argument checking in any case.  With that being so, it seems a little strange to call out `NULL` pointers as a special case to catch.

While I'm at it, as long as you are targeting C99 or later, and you don't need to support swapping enormous objects, you would get much better performance by allocating temporary space on the stack, via a variable-length array, than you do by allocating it on the heap:

```
void genericSwap(void *x, void *y, size_t size)
{
    unsigned char temp[size];

    memcpy(temp, x, size);
    memcpy(x, y, size);
    memcpy(y, temp, size);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. "You cannot test whether the size of the referents is correct, nor whether the pointer arguments are invalid despite being non-NULL." I know that I cannot check the size of the referents. Could you give an example when the pointer arguments would be invalid despite being non-NULL? I guess when they have different types.

Comment: The pointer arguments could be invalid despite being non-NULL if they were never initialized (this case does not necessarily yield NULL pointers), or if they were once valid pointers, but the memory they pointed to has since been freed.

Comment: So following your argument, you would drop the `if`-checks on the arguments for non-NULL pointers because not all possible cases where this could go wrong can be checked and only check `malloc()`?

Comment: @brauner, I provided an example of exactly what I would do.  If I did use `malloc()`, though, then yes, I would check its return value.  As for *why* I would do it that way, I generally account it the user's responsibility to provide valid arguments, particularly when there isn't really a good way of handling invalid ones.  In this case, `NULL` arguments aren't even the most likely form for invalid arguments, so it seems kinda pointless to test for them in particular.

Comment: Also, I account a segmentation fault / access violation exception / etc. a far better response to dereferencing an invalid pointer (NULL or otherwise), than a message on stderr.  Not that such a fault is guaranteed to occur, but generally speaking, you get it for free.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a "brutal exit", you can declare the function as `int genericSwap(…)` and return `TRUE` or `FALSE` (1 or 0) depending on success. The caller can now do the following and decide whether to exit or recover in some way:

```
if (!GenericSwap(p1, p2, sizeof(*p1))) { // handle error
```

Comment: Given C99, you could use `<stdbool.h>` and `bool` and `true` or `false`, too.